# Which Win32 Functions used by Windows Resource Monitor to detect both disk and network activities for terminated process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

In **Windows Resource Monitor** there are four tabs - **CPU,MEMORY,DISK,NETWORK**
This program shows us every process with their respective **PID**(process ID) which are involving with I/O activities with disk drives and network.

### Issue

I am using Win32 Programming plus Visual C++(Visual Studio).I created a process(Using **CreateProcess** function) "VBS3_64.exe",suppose that I don't know it's internal behavior,In my program my only intention was to create that process,let it execute for several minutes and Terminate it using **Terminate** or **SendMessage** functions.
After I terminate that process progrmatically **Windows Resource monitor** shown that both CPU and Memory usage on **"Terminated"** state(gray color) but both Disk activity and Network activity were running(black color) at the moment for several minutes. Even **Windows Task Manager** did not show that Process.

I used Win32 functions to check whether that the process still running on the system even it get called Terminate or force kill but all of those function given me the same result.**But only Resource Monitor detects its clean up -Disk activities and Network activities**.

---

### Question

1. How terminated process still Run in background for its cleanup stuff and only Resource Monitor detects it with its respective **PID** ?
2. Which Win32 functions helps us to detect such Process ? 
   (which Win32 functions is being used by Resource Monitor to detect background/clean up activities of Terminated process).

Please refer following question that I asked on MSDN :- [MSDN QUESTION](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5aae0de-0056-4875-818b-2d9de465e883/how-to-measure-process-with-disk-activity-and-network-activity-like-windows-resource-monitor?forum=windowssdk)

Comment: What does "pure Win32 Visual C++ functions" mean to you?  The functions you are using to get the information are very much Windows specific.  Is your code not working?

Comment: Visual C++ and WIN32 are two very different things. One is an implementation of a compiler and standard library and the other is the OS API.

Comment: Have you noticed that Windows resource monitor shows Process disk activity and network activity if that process dealing with such operations  even process has been terminated. I want to know how does Windows Resource monitor  monitoring such process activities even if it's statues in "Terminated"

Comment: Difficult to divine a question here. It looks like you might have written some code and forgotten to attempt to debug it.

Comment: this is not full code,but separate approaches. I think you can grasp basic idea if you know win32 api.I tried those function to count Disk I/O operations.

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: Please refer following question asked by me on MSDN
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5aae0de-0056-4875-818b-2d9de465e883/how-to-measure-process-with-disk-activity-and-network-activity-like-windows-resource-monitor?forum=windowssdk

Comment: @BuddhikaGamage: If you close and re-open Resource Monitor, will you still see this?

Comment: @Mehrdad 
No now it's gone!!! :| is it a Resource monitor real-time result generating bug? yeah both Disk activity and network activity gone for that process!!How that latency exist on such thoroughly tested software(WRM)?

Comment: @Mehrdad So is it a WRM bug or latency? or (I am using win10) Windows managed that process and its cleanups after it's  terminated on WINAPI level (outside API boundary cannot touch it but internal OS core function can )?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too hard. The process is already terminated... that means it's gone.
Resource Monitor is just showing you the information a little longer so you have a chance to see it.

Comment: That's not correct. The kernel keeps process **objects** around, even for processes that have terminated. Unlike Linux, you can reliably query e.g. a process' exit code, as long as you have an open handle to the process object. I'm going to have to down-vote this answer for being wildly inaccurate.

Comment: @IInspectable: How the hell is that even relevant here? I don't see a single process handle open in Resource Monitor, so I'm pretty damn sure that's not what's happening.

Comment: *"I don't see a single process handle open in Resource Monitor"* - Correct. Apparently, *Resource Monitor* doesn't show process handles.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, when I said "in" Resource Monitor I meant in Resource Monitor's process. I wasn't referring to the handles you see in the program UI. I was inspecting it using Process Hacker. Go check it out yourself if you don't believe me. I'm pretty damn sure you're wrong. Provide some evidence otherwise.

Comment: I see lots of open *Thread* handles, which indirectly prevent the owning processes from getting disposed. Speaking of which, can you provide evidence that *Resource Monitor* works the way you suggest? (Besides, *Resource Monitor* isn't just *"Resource Monitor's process"*. Open process handles could be in whichever component *Resource Monitor* uses.)